# MCV 3 Razor, best way to send info to modal box

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model in MVC 3 that i'm passing into a strongly typed view, the model contains information about an employee. Here is where I am having trouble. I have an edit button that when I press it, it should open a modal box with with all the labels for the employee info in text box form and pre filled with the info from the model.

right now i'm using javascript to find the label elements and then get their innerText. This seems to work fine, but I would really like to stick to using a model as much as I can because  some of the labels when you go to edit them aren't free text they are going to need to be drop downs.

Just any information about why I shouldn't or should do it with JavaScript.

Comment: Why not instead show the contents via a partial view in your modal dialog?

Comment: I think you're confused on some things here. MVC is a way of rendering webpages, not some magic that makes all things happen in a dynamic way. For what you're describing, you should either prepopulate something on the page with the data you need, or make AJAX calls to the server to get the data you need and then use jQuery or some similar (you could write your own, but cross browser incompatibilities are a pain) framework to populate all that data. There is no magic here, we all do the same stuff, and we all either prepopulate or generate on the fly.

Comment: I'm newer to MVC thanks for the input guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of situation I usually make an ajax call to the server and have that return a partial view. Then use jQuery to put the returned partial view into your modal popup.
Here's a brief list of what you should need to make this happen:

1. Have a partial view strongly typed to your employee model that contains the edit form
2. Make your edit link do an ajax call to an action on your controller and send the employee id or something so you can generate an employee object in your action
3. In your action return the Partial View containing the form and pass in the employee object
4. In your success function on the ajax call take the html returned from the call and insert it into your modal popup

Comment: Thank you, this was the direction i was leaning towards and since it's method you seem to have down I'm going to go ahead and give this a try.

Comment: It's always worked pretty good for me. And it seems a lot more clean than using jQuery to scrape the page and fill in the values of a blank form

Comment: I've completed the form and it works great using this method, thanks again